# What I am doing wrong in this correlation query in oracle SqlDevelopper

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, correlation

I'm trying to build a query to select the correlation coefficient as to determine the most rated movie by a user

The structure of my table is like this:

[image]

My query is this:

```
SELECT  
    user1, user2,
    ((psum - (sum1 * sum2 / n)) / sqrt((sum1sq - pow(sum1, 2.0) / n) * (sum2sq - pow(sum2, 2.0) / n))) AS r,
    n
FROM
    (SELECT 
         n1.idclient AS user1,
         n2.idclient AS user2,
         SUM(n1.cote) AS sum1,
         SUM(n2.cote) AS sum2,
         SUM(n1.cote * n1.cote) AS sum1sq,
         SUM(n2.cote * n2.cote) AS sum2sq,
         SUM(n1.cote * n2.cote) AS psum,
         COUNT(*) AS n
     FROM
         cote AS n1 // <---------- Editor is pointing a missing parenthese here with a red line 
    LEFT JOIN
        cote AS n2 ON n1.idfilm = n2.idfilm
    WHERE   
        n1.idclient > n2.idclient
    GROUP BY
        n1.idclient, n2.idclient) AS step1
ORDER BY
    r DESC, n DESC
```

But I'm confident that I  haven't miss a parentheses, what did I do wrong?

P.S : I'm not an expert and I would like to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle doesn't let you use `AS` for table aliases, only for column aliases. [The select-list syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2126854) shows an optional `AS`; [the table-reference syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2126863) does not.

In the line you highlighted

```
FROM cote AS n1
```

the `AS` is being treated as the table alias (although it's a reserved word so you can't use it for an alias); then it sees the `n1` and doesn't know what it means. The parser often seems to fall back to guessing that any open parentheses should have been closed, immediately before that `n1` token in this case, as that could have completed what it had parsed so far (I'm very much simplifying, of course); hence the not entirely helpful error message.

So you need to remove the `AS` from all three places you're using it:

```
SELECT  
        user1, user2,
        ((psum - (sum1 * sum2 / n)) / sqrt((sum1sq - pow(sum1, 2.0) / n) * (sum2sq - pow(sum2, 2.0) / n))) AS r,
        n
FROM
        (SELECT 
                n1.idclient AS user1,
                n2.idclient AS user2,
                SUM(n1.cote) AS sum1,
                SUM(n2.cote) AS sum2,
                SUM(n1.cote * n1.cote) AS sum1sq,
                SUM(n2.cote * n2.cote) AS sum2sq,
                SUM(n1.cote * n2.cote) AS psum,
                COUNT(*) AS n
        FROM
                cote n1
    LEFT JOIN
        cote n2
    ON
        n1.idfilm = n2.idfilm
        WHERE   
                n1.idclient > n2.idclient
    GROUP BY
        n1.idclient, n2.idclient) step1
ORDER BY
        r DESC,
        n DESC
```

Comment: "Oracle doesn't let you use AS for table aliases, only for column aliases. In the line you highlighted" , oh my god , now I understand why sometimes I can use AS and sometimes I cannot , but the weird thing is in some other oracle editor it accept it , ......Oracle is a big world and I thank you very much for your time explaining it to me

Comment: Even if your other editor didn't highlight the problem, you would have got the same ORA-00907 error when you ran the query.

Comment: Yup , you are right because when I run the query , it didn't recognize "POW" but instead recognized POWER . I never understood why Oracle never like to be uniformed and use the same syntax in all versions . It's not hard , but it confuses me

Comment: I don't think `pow` has ever been valid in Oracle, it's been `power` in all versions I've used.  Other databases use other syntax of course, including accepting `AS` for table aliases, and `pow` (in MySQL I think). Anyway, glad it's sorted.